# How to import both ViewPagerIndicator and ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, maven

If i only using `ViewPagerIndicator` as dependency project, then everything goes fine. But after i import `ActionBarSherlock`, something wrong happens.

Here is the output log:

```
125 || [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
126 || [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
127 || [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
128 || [INFO] Total time: 33.129s
129 || [INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 19 14:33:23 CST 2013
130 || [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/102M
131 || [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
132 || [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.2-SNAPSHOT:dex (default-dex) on project rms:                     MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /Users/ccheng/workspace/rms && /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.       jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -jar /Users/ccheng/program/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/lib/dx.jar --dex --output=/Users/ccheng/           workspace/rms/target/classes.dex /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/google/        code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/biubiubiu/indexablelistview-lib2/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/indexablelistview-lib2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /      Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/biubiubiu/indexablelistview-lib1/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/indexablelistview-lib1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/novoda/    imageloader/imageloader-core/1.5.8/imageloader-core-1.5.8.jar /Use
133 || rs/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/github/chrisbanes/pulltorefresh/library/2.1.1/library-2.1.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/workspace/rms/target/classes /Users/ccheng/.m2/         repository/com/tjerkw/slideexpandablelistview-library/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/slideexpandablelistview-library-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/google/      android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/msx/android/preferences/libraryprojects-lib1/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/libraryprojects-lib1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.    apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.3.1/actionbarsherlock-4.3.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/meishixing/android-    async-http/1.4.2/android-async-http-1.4.2.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/library-2.4.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/       android/support/compatibility-v4/18/compatibility-v4-18.jar, Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
134 || [ERROR]
135 || [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
136 || [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
137 || [ERROR]
138 || [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
139 || [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
140 || make: *** [main] Error 1


➜  /tmp  /bin/sh -c cd /Users/ccheng/workspace/rms && /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -jar /Users/ccheng/program/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/lib/dx.jar --dex --output=/Users/ccheng/workspace/rms/target/classes.dex /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/biubiubiu/indexablelistview-lib2/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/indexablelistview-lib2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/biubiubiu/indexablelistview-lib1/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/indexablelistview-lib1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/novoda/imageloader/imageloader-core/1.5.8/imageloader-core-1.5.8.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/github/chrisbanes/pulltorefresh/library/2.1.1/library-2.1.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/workspace/rms/target/classes /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/tjerkw/slideexpandablelistview-library/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/slideexpandablelistview-library-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/msx/android/preferences/libraryprojects-lib1/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/libraryprojects-lib1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.3.1/actionbarsherlock-4.3.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/meishixing/android-async-http/1.4.2/android-async-http-1.4.2.jar /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/com/viewpagerindicator/biubiubiu-library/2.4.1/biubiubiu-library-2.4.1.apklib /Users/ccheng/.m2/repository/android/support/compatibility-v4/18/compatibility-v4-18.jar

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManagerState;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me.biubiubiu.rms</groupId>
    <artifactId>rms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>rms</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <fest-assert.version>1.0.4</fest-assert.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <robolectric.version>2.0</robolectric.version>
        <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
        <android-support.version>r13</android-support.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tjerkw</groupId>
            <artifactId>slideexpandablelistview-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.meishixing</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>biubiubiu-library</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.4.1</version>-->
            <!--<type>apklib</type>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
          <artifactId>library</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
          <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.chrisbanes.pulltorefresh</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.novoda.imageloader</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageloader-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.biubiubiu</groupId>
            <artifactId>indexablelistview-lib2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-android</artifactId>
            <version>${fest-assert.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>${robolectric.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>msx.android.preferences</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <manifest>
                        <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!--jarsign-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sign</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <archiveDirectory></archiveDirectory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>target/*.apk</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <keystore>/Users/ccheng/workspace/msx-crazysight/meishixing.keystore</keystore>
                                    <storepass>meishigo</storepass>
                                    <keypass>meishigo</keypass>
                                    <alias>meishixing</alias>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-sigalg</argument><argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                                        <argument>-digestalg</argument><argument>SHA1</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the problem is with ActionBarSherlock, try using ActionBarActivity which is available in v7 support library

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem is caused by the v4 library i import is different from `ActionBarSherlock`.

After i change all the dependency project to

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>
```

it works find again.